# Is materialized view concept same as an indexed view in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have always worked with SQL server.

I have recently come across materialized view (heard of this in a general database presentation):

> The basic difference between View and Materialized View is that Views
> are not stored physically on the disk. On the other hands,
> Materialized Views are stored on the disc.

Is materialized view concept same as an indexed view in SQL server?

Comment: They have similarities. They have differences. The "sameness" of them depends on whether you care more about the similarities than the differences.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well done...  A factually correct, yet completely null statement.

Comment: Materialized View generally refers to Oracle's implementation, which needs to be periodically refreshed. SQL Server's Indexed Views are updated in real-time

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found in Microsoft's documentation. (The emphasis in the quoted material is mine.)

I could be wrong, but it appears that Microsoft uses the term "Materialized View" specifically with Azure Synapse Analytics, and not with SQL Server generally.

From [Views (SQL Server 2019)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15#types-of-views)

> #### Indexed Views
>
> An **indexed view** is a view that has been **materialized**. This means the
> view definition has been computed and the resulting data stored just
> like a table. You index a view by creating a unique clustered index on
> it. Indexed views can dramatically improve the performance of some
> types of queries. Indexed views work best for queries that aggregate
> many rows. They are not well-suited for underlying data sets that are
> frequently updated.

From [CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-materialized-view-as-select-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest#remarks)

*Applies to Azure Synapse Analytics*

> #### Remarks
>
> **A materialized view in Azure data warehouse is similar to an indexed**
> **view in SQL Server.**  It shares almost the same restrictions as indexed
> view (see [Create Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=azure-sqldw-latest) for details) except that a materialized
> view supports aggregate functions.

Comment: SQL Server did also seem to toy with an idea of snapshot materialisation that never came to fruition https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187533/3690